# Calling subprocess in python with special character

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a script which takes password from password manager API, and create ssh session with this line

```
subprocess.call(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'ssh', '-l', username, url])
```

However I have a little problem with this, if in password are some special characters e.g. this password is problem

```
*jadKWI_3ekd}ad2+
```

If I am trying to connect somewhere, through my python script, with password, which contains these special characters, I get error message from ssh:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I have tried this command in shell and it works without any problem

```
sshpass -p "*jadKWI_3ekd}ad2+" ssh url -l username
```

Could someone help me, if there is any solution how to solve this issue? I have found that some people solve similar problem to use raw string, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Why is that example a problem? Can you be more specific with what goes wrong when such input is used?

Comment: Are you facing log-in issues, when the password has special characters?

Comment: There should be no issues with special characters as long as `shell=False` which it is by default.

Comment: I have edited question. I am not able to login, if there is some special characters. I get error message Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: You are providing twice the password in your call, remove the last one to do the same as in your shown shell command

Comment: @CarlosHorn sorry, I just made a mistake, when I wrote this question. In my script it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Shell special characters in the `ssh` command will be evaluated by the *remote* shell unless you quote or escape them.

Try this:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

subprocess.check_call(
    ['sshpass', '-p', password,
     'ssh', '-l', username, 
             shlex.quote(password)])
```

Generally prefer `check_call` over the very crude `call` interface unless you specifically want to ignore errors.

(Perhaps also look into the modern replacement `subprocess.run`, though the legacy `check_*` functions from Python 2 are convenient shorthands for the situations where their limitations and lack of flexibility are not a problem.)

It's not clear why you are trying to use the password as the name of the host to connect to, anyway; probably this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). But if that's really what you want, this is how to do it.

There are obviously situations where you do want to pass strings with shell metacharacters to the remote `ssh`, like for example

```
matches = subprocess.run(
    ["ssh", "hostname",
     "grep", shlex.quote(".*"), "ick.txt"],
    check=True, text=True.
    capture_output=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have just made a mistake when I was writing question. Instead of password, there should be variable with url. I have edited question.

Comment: Connecting interactively through a subprocess will have other problems, and frankly, I think your question is still not complete. If you are really seeking to run an interactive SSH session from Python, probably look into `paramiko` or perhaps `pexpect`.